# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [LdapService] with qualifiers [@Named] at injection point

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi, weblogic12c

Hello I'm trying to deploy an EAR to my Weblogic server 12c (12.1.3) without success.

My LdapService class is a Stateless EJB with default no args constructor (This project is an ejb package)

```
@Stateless
public class LdapService {

@Inject
public LdapService() {

} ...
```

I'm trying to inject it to another class like:

```
public class UserService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class.getCanonicalName());
@Inject
private LdapService registerService;

@EJB(beanName = "Janus-session-1.0.jar#UserBean")
private TUserBean userBean;

...}
```

The bean annotated with @EJB it's recognized by the CDI, but the injection point throws me this error about the @Inject:

> Deployment failed. The message was: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: 
>   WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [LdapService] with qualifiers 
>   [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject net.ab4cus.project.business.TransactionService.registerService]. 
>   Possible dependencies [[Session bean [class net.ab4cus.project.auth.LdapService 
>   with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [LdapService]]

If in LdapService use @Named("LdapService") and then at the injection point use:

```
@Inject @Named("LdapService") private LdapService registerService;
```

Then I got this error:

> Deployment failed. The message was: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied 
>   dependencies for type [LdapService] with qualifiers [@Named] at injection 
>   point [[field] @Inject @Named net.ab4cus.project.business.UserService.registerService]

How do I can solve this error and remove the ambiguity? or what is the correct way to do @Inject to other beans?

Thank You.

**EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I managed to deploy the EAR, but now have other errors involving the CDI.

My EAR contents are: EJB module (with the beans and all the business logic) and two WAR's (One for WebServices and one for a Web FronEnd using Vaadin).

The WebServices are RESTFull, and no matter what WS I try to consume, get always this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:94)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:314)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

If I try with the frontend, any time a bean is accesed I get this error (for each bean):

```
SEVERE: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set net.ab4cus.project.session.TUserBean field net.ab4cus.project.business.UserService.userBean to net.ab4cus.project.session.UserBean_o7pydo_NoIntfViewImpl
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
```

I'm trying to resolve this, but for now have no clue :/

Comment: Remove `@Inject` from the LdapService constructor, it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Gas, I already tried that and get the same error: `Deployment failed. The message was: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [LdapService] with qualifiers [@Named] at injection point [[field] @Inject @Named net.ab4cus.janus.business.UserService.registerService].` 

By the way if I don't annotate LdapService with @Inject in the constructor, when I try to make and instance of the bean (uploading the war) I only get a null at the injection point :/

Comment: You should also removed `@Named`, as it is only used to make bean available in JSP/JSF. It can be used in the bean class or producer method, not with `@Inject`.

Comment: Removed the `@Named` and the `@Inject` in LdapService but still get the WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies. If I remove the Injection completely of the project, the EAR deploys successfully :/

Comment: Looks like a bit different problems as it deploys successfully now. I'd suggest to create two separate questions, one for WS problem, other for front end problem as they may have different causes and solutions.

Comment: You error message with `Possible dependencies`... Are you sure that this is a complete message? Weld should give you at least two possibilities when calling it ambiguous.

Comment: Try to deploy only one WAR at the time and investigate one issue at the time, when every war is working, bundle them together and deploy. Also you need to create new questions for other issues. And please close this one with a solution what you found for original issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution for my first error was:

-Removing the @Stateless and @Inject from LdapService and the default constructor

```
public class LdapService {

}...
```

-Create an Interface for LdapService and @Inject this interface to UserService

```
public class UserService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class.getCanonicalName());
@Inject
private LdapServiceInterface registerService;

@EJB(beanName = "Janus-session-1.0.jar#UserBean")
private TUserBean userBean;

...}
```

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, can you tell me why is it a problem to post a question in multiple forums ?

Comment: @RITZXAVI http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @AbhijeetSarkar, the link you shared talks about when(if at all) a question is a good candidate for cross-posting within stackexchange sites.I completely agree to it in the sense that a question should not be posted in more than one forum within stack exchange.But it doesn't talk about restricting one from posting same question on forums not owned by stackexchange(eg coderanch and oracle in this case). Infact posting questions in different communities will give more insight on the question as well as on the answers.I guess your downvote here and comments on those websites are inappropriate.